# Handle async operation in Redux

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, asynchronous, draftjs

I am trying to render `post.paragraph` coming from the Redux store.

This is the code I am using:

```js
    const postDetails = useSelector((state) => state.postDetails);
    const { loading, post, error } = postDetails; 

    const editorContent =   post ?
    EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(post.paragraph))) : 
    EditorState.createEmpty();
    
    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState({ editorState: editorContent });
    
    const handleEditorChange = (editorState) => { setEditorState({ editorState }) }
    
    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(
          updatePost({
            _id: id,
            title,
            image,
            images,
            paragraph: JSON.stringify(
              convertToRaw(editorState.editorState.getCurrentContent())
            ),
          })
        );
      };
    
    <Editor
       editorState={editorState.editorState}
       onEditorStateChange={handleEditorChange}
     />
```

Though it seems like it takes time for `post.paragraph` to display therefore my app fails. In fact, if I `console.log(post.paragraph)` I get "undefined" twice and only then I get my `post.paragraph` displayed.

[image]

To fix the issue i tried to put everything in an if statement like this:

```js
    const postDetails = useSelector((state) => state.postDetails);
        const { loading, post, error } = postDetails; 
        const content = (async (err, res) => {
        const editorContent = await post.paragraph;
          if (post.paragraph) {
            res.send({ editorContent: EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(post.paragraph))) });
          } else {
              res.send({ editorContent: EditorState.createEmpty()});
            }
            return editorContent;
          })
    
    
        const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState({ editorState: content });
        
        const handleEditorChange = (editorState) => { setEditorState({ editorState }) }
        
        const submitHandler = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            dispatch(
              updatePost({
                _id: id,
                title,
                image,
                images,
                paragraph: JSON.stringify(
                  convertToRaw(editorState.editorState.getCurrentContent())
                ),
              })
            );
          };
        
        <Editor
           editorState={editorState.editorState}
           onEditorStateChange={handleEditorChange}
         />
```

But now the error I get is the following:

[image]

I also tried the following, but i get the same error:

```js
    const postDetails = useSelector((state) => state.postDetails);
        const { loading, post, error } = postDetails; 
          const editorContent =   !loading ?
    EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(post.paragraph))) : 
    EditorState.createEmpty();
    
        const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState({ editorState: editorContent });
        
        const handleEditorChange = (editorState) => { setEditorState({ editorState }) }
        
        const submitHandler = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            dispatch(
              updatePost({
                _id: id,
                title,
                image,
                images,
                paragraph: JSON.stringify(
                  convertToRaw(editorState.editorState.getCurrentContent())
                ),
              })
            );
          };
        
        <Editor
           editorState={editorState.editorState}
           onEditorStateChange={handleEditorChange}
         />
```

How should I tackle this async request? Many thanks!

Comment: Instead of going for async await, you can use the loading state to check whether the api call is pending and if the response is loaded then set your initial value as `post.paragraph`. Try this.
`
 const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState({ editorState: !loading ? post.paragraph :   ' ' });
`

Comment: Hi thanks. I tried, but it doesn't work. See the edited post.